# Cypher query to find the hop depth length of particular relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to find the amount of relationships that stem originally from a parent node and I am not sure the syntax to use in order to gain access to this returned integer. I am can be sure in my code that each child node can only have one relationship of a particular type so this allows me to capture a "true" depth reading

My attempt is this but I am hoping there is a cleaner way:

```
MATCH p=(n {id:'123'})-[r:Foo*]->(c)
RETURN length(p)
```

I am not sure this is the correct syntax because it returns an array of integers with the last index being the true tally length. I am hoping for something that just returns an int instead of this mentioned array.

I am very grateful for help that you may be able to offer.

Comment: Are you trying to find the maximum depth or just the number of outgoing `:Foo` relationships?

Comment: trying to find maximum depth

Comment: Then just wrap it in `MAX`. `RETURN MAX(LENGTH(p))`. Your query is very expensive, though, and will most likely not even finish on a large enough graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Nicole says, in general, finding the longest path between two nodes in a graph is not feasible in any reasonable time. If your graph is very small, it is possible that you will be able to find all paths, and select the one with the most edges but this won't scale to larger graphs.

However there is a trick that you can do in certain circumstances. **If your graph contains no directed cycles**, you can assign each edge a weight of -1, and then look for the *shortest weighted path* between the source and target nodes. Since the edge weights are negative a shortest weighted path must correspond to a path with a maximum number of edges between the desired nodes.

Unfortunately, Cypher doesn't yet support shortest weighted path algorithms, however the Neo4j database engine does. The docs give an example of how to do this. You will also need to implement your own algorithm, such as Bellman-Ford using the traversal API, because Dijkstra won't work with -ve edge weights.

However, please be aware that this trick won't work if your graph contains cycles - it **must** be a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).

Answer (score 1):

Your query:

```
MATCH p=(n {id:'123'})-[r:Foo*]->(c)
RETURN length(p)
```

is returning the length of **ALL** possible paths from `n` to `c`. You probably are only interested in the shortest path? You can use the `shortestPath` function to only consider the shortest path from `n` to `c`:

```
MATCH p = shortestPath((n {id:'123'})-[r:Foo*]->(c))
RETURN length(p)
```